# Application-defined or object-defined error vba 1

Tags: vba

Here is my code, it s simple! but i have an error
at this line "wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(3, j), Cells(10, j)).Select"

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ms As Workbook
  Dim Path As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer

Set ms = ThisWorkbook


Path = "D:\SYSTEM DATA\\EVT.xlsx"

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Path)

wb.Activate
For i = 2 To 12 Step 1
If wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, i).Value = "EVT006" Then
j = i
Exit For
End If
Next i

wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(3, j), Cells(10, j)).Select 'the error line
Selection.Copy


ms.Activate
With ms
Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

wb.Close True
End Sub
```

i dont know why ?
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to declare your wb on your cells within the range as well.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ms As Workbook
  Dim Path As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer

Set ms = ThisWorkbook


Path = "D:\SYSTEM DATA\\EVT.xlsx"

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Path)

wb.Activate
For i = 2 To 12 Step 1
If wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, i).Value = "EVT006" Then
j = i
Exit For
End If
Next i

wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, j), wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, j)).Select 'the error line
Selection.Copy


ms.Activate
With ms
Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

wb.Close True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank Brad for your help

Comment: Not a problem! :) Glad I could @Mchich

Answer (score 0):

in

```
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(3, j), Cells(10, j)).Select
```

you have `wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(` referencing worksheet "Sheet1" of workbook `wb`, while `Cells(3, j)` and `Cells(10, j)` are referencing *active* sheet of *active* workbook, where this latter is still `wb` (due to preceeding `wb.Activate`) while the former is the worksheet `wb` is opening with (i.e. the *active* sheet at the time it was last saved) which is not assured in any way to be "Sheet1"

furthemore you should avoid `Activate`/`Select`/`ActiveXXX`/`Selection` pattern and use fully qualified range references

finally you wouldn't need any `wb.Activate` statement after `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Path)` one, since at any workbook opening it becomes the *Active* one

so substitute

```
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(3, j), Cells(10, j)).Select 'the error line
Selection.Copy


ms.Activate
With ms
Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```

with

```
With Wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range(.Cells(3, j), .Cells(10, j)).Copy
    ms.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```

Comment: Would the brave downvoter mind explaining the reason why so as to both have me enhance my answer and other people learn from his contribution?

Comment: Sorry guys, i wasn't online!

its working perfectly, now i have to improve and add other things
I'm leeeeearning!

Comment: Love you gays, really